# Trying to access and object with spaces in property names in template7 literal

Tags: javascript, literals, templating, html-framework-7

I am using template7 template engine and having a problem when it comes to an object that has spaces as property names. Usually in js they can be accessed by using brackets `myObject['property with spaces']`. In the case of template7 variables in my html template, I cannot seem to access these properties this way.

example:

```
{{#if data.actions['CONFIRM CANCEL']}}
```

my object:

```
{data: "actions":{"CONFIRM CANCEL":"49"}}
```

Looking for any suggestions on how i could select this property within a template7 expression?

Comment: Try with an additional dot before `[]` like this: `data.actions.[CONFIRM CANCEL]`

Comment: I did also try with the . before the [] and it gives a syntax error